# How to set basic authentication with apache camel and http4

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I'm trying to use Apache Camel's Http4 component to connect to a HTTP URL that needs Basic authentication. I'm setting credentials from a camel processor through **Exchange.HTTP_QUERY** header. I configure my route like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint ...>

<bean id="myProcessor"
    class="com.myCompany.Bean"
    factory-method="myProcessorBean">
</bean>

<camelContext id="myContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    
    <route id="myRoute>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:myQueue" />
        <process ref="myProcessor" />
        <to uri="http4://oldhost"/>
    </route>
        
</camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

and my processor looks like:

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  String user = getUserFromDB();
  String pwd = getPasswordFromDB();

  String queryParameters = "authMethod=Basic&authPassword="+pwd+"authUsername="+user;
  exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, queryParameters);
  exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, "api.abc_company.com/service/to/consume");
  ....
}
```

It results in:

```
Error myContext: org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https://api.abc_company.com/service/to/consume?authMethod=Basic&authPassword=xxxxxx&authUsername=test with statusCode: 401
```

It seems that **password was changed to xxxxxx** but I'm not sure.

When I try hardcoding user and password in the URI it works well, however I need a way to set these values programmatically due to user and password are stored it the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "authMethod=Basic&authPassword="+pwd+"authUsername="+user;

You'll need to at & between each uri parameter.  You're missing one after password.

Try:

```java
String queryParameters = "authMethod=Basic&authPassword="+pwd+"&authUsername="+user;
```

Also you should define credentials in producer endpoint URI `http4://oldhost?authMethod=Basic&authPassword="+pwd+"&authUsername="+user` instead of header: `Exchange.HTTP_QUERY`.

If you want to do this in your processor you can try to set `Authorization` [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) manually with value `basic <credentials>` where `<credentials>` is base64 encoded `username:password`.

> Failed invoking https://api.abc_company.com/service/to/consume?

If you want to connect to https site use `https4://`

Comment: Actually I was already using &, it was a bug in the example. I tested setting a header and it works fine. Thanks a lot.